# How to iterate through all dictionary combinations

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, combinatorics

Consider I have the following dictionary:

```py
someDict = {
  'A': [1,2,3],
  'B': [4,5,6],
  'C': [7,8,9]
}
```

Is there an easy way I can iterate through to create new dictionaries in a loop for all of the possible combinations, ie?

```
{'A' : 1, 'B': 4, 'C':7}
{'A' : 1, 'B': 4, 'C':8}
{'A' : 1, 'B': 4, 'C':9}
{'A' : 2, 'B': 4, 'C':7}
```

etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) as follows:

```
from itertools import product

someDict = {
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': [4, 5, 6],
    'C': [7, 8, 9]
}

keys, values = zip(*someDict.items())
result = [dict(zip(keys, p)) for p in product(*values)]

for d in result:
    print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 8}
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 9}
{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 8}
{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 9}
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 8}
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 8}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 9}
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 8}
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 9}
{'A': 2, 'B': 6, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 6, 'C': 8}
{'A': 2, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}
{'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 8}
{'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 9}
{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 7}
{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 8}
{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 9}
{'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 7}
{'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 8}
{'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with `product`:

```
p = product(*[product(k, v) for k, v in someDict.items()])

for i in p:
    print(dict(i))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 8}
{'A': 1, 'B': 4, 'C': 9}
{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 8}
{'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 9}
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 7}
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 8}
{'A': 1, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 8}
{'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 9}
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 8}
{'A': 2, 'B': 5, 'C': 9}
{'A': 2, 'B': 6, 'C': 7}
{'A': 2, 'B': 6, 'C': 8}
{'A': 2, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}
{'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 7}
{'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 8}
{'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 9}
{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 7}
{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 8}
{'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 9}
{'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 7}
{'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 8}
{'A': 3, 'B': 6, 'C': 9}
```